# Run ElasticSearch using Python

Tags: python, shell, elasticsearch, cmd

I am trying to turn on ElasticSearch node using python. I am doing this by running a shell script via python. I have tried the below commands in python to run the shell script :

```
import os
cmd = 'cd C:\Users\anoop\desktop\kibi\elasticsearch 2.3.3\bin && .\elasticsearch'
os.system(cmd)


from subprocess import call
call('cd C:\Users\anoop\desktop\kibi\elasticsearch 2.3.3\bin && .\elasticsearch')


import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('C:\Users\anoop\Desktop\RunES.bat', shell = True)
p.communicate()
```

None of the above three methods is working. Let me know if anyone can help on this!!

Comment: You have to run ./elasticsearch.bat file on windows. Just ./elasticsearch is for unix systems.
I guess os.system() is now deprecated. You should stick to subprocess. Try running simple commands like "dir" to check for any errors.

Comment: try this `subprocess.Popen('C:\Users\anoop\desktop\kibi\elasticsearch 2.3.3\bin\elasticsearch.bat')`.

Comment: Thanks!! subprocess.Popen() worked!!